# CKEditor Table Header lose formatting

Tags: datatable, formatting, ckeditor

I have a problem with CKEditor (Version 4.5.7). I have a table with formatted text in the first line (bold and centered). The problem appears when I put the cursor in the first cell and switch to the next cell with tab. The text in the next cell is then selected and that's ok. But when I start typing new text in this cell to overwrite the selected text, it loses the formatting. This happens not in every cell. This is a behaviour in Mozilla Firefox and in Internet Explorer. Chrome seems to be ok. Is this a known issue and is there a solution for this.

Comment: please provide a working example, and if it looks like a bug just [open a bug report](https://dev.ckeditor.com/wiki/Bugs)

Comment: I can reproduce the issue. I downloaded the code from here http://ckeditor.com/download/releases as zip.
I opened the example and created a table with bold text in the cells of the first line. Then I put cursor to the first
cell and switched to next cell with tab. When I start typing text, the bold formatting is lost. Think it is a bug?

Comment: According to that comment - yes, this is a correct behavior, however it will be much better if you can provide a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), as it's not so clear how you "created a table with bold text in the cells of the first line". What do you mean by "first line"? How exactly did you do it?

Comment: Ok, line is the wrong word. Row is the correct word here. Sorry for that. I created the table with the button for tables in ckeditor and inserted text in every cell in the first row with bold formatting.

Comment: It seems like you are talking about usage and not about programming, so it's not exactly the place for such question.

Comment: What I mean is, I integrated the ckeditor in a website in our project. And when I use the table in the editor as described I got this problem with lost formatting. My question is, is this a bug, because it happens in Firefox and Internet Explorer but not in Chrome. In Chrome is the formatting correct after switching with tab in the table. Where is the correct place for this question?

Comment: Since your question is **not** related to programming (but front-end usage) it's not belong to stackoverflow. Regardless - if the behavior is not the same in all browsers - it seems like a bug.